# xtrlock : how to set/change the password

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just discovered the xtrlock app. Can anyone answer the following questions, since the man page does not cover this:
1. "How do you set the initial password on xtrlock?"
2. "How do you change the password on xtrlock?"
Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You do not set the password on xtrlock. It uses your regular login password.

In addition, xtrlock does not support PAM-based password checking and *always* expects to find the user's password hash in /etc/shadow. This means that 1) there is no way to make xtrlock-specific password settings, 2) it won't work with LDAP/AD user accounts, 3) it has to start with root privileges which is a security risk.